# multiple select in one query [Teradata]

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count, teradata

I'm trying to do multiple select from diff tables and just have a result in one column.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb1 union
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb2 union
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb3;
```

output should be like:

```
 593643
 18103600
 0
```

Problem with this is that the result is being arranged on desc order.
Like below:

```
 0
 593643
 18103600
```

I would want the result to be as I put the select statement.
Please advise. Btw, I'm using teradata.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL result sets are inherently unordered, unless you explicitly specify an `order by` clause.  You can do this with a subquery:

```
select cnt
from ((SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, 1 as ord FROM tb1)
      union all
      (SELECT COUNT(*), 2 FROM tb2)
      union all
      (SELECT COUNT(*), 3 FROM tb3)
     ) t
order by ord
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want specific order, add `ORDER BY` clause. It would also be good to use `UNION ALL` so you always get 3 rows, even with duplicate results (two tables having the same number of rows):

```
SELECT 'tbl1' AS tablename, COUNT(*) AS cnt, 1 AS ord FROM tb1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbl2', COUNT(*), 2 FROM tb2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'tbl3', COUNT(*), 3 FROM tb3
ORDER BY ord ;
```